# UITableView Not Populating on Initial load , is Populating on Subsequent loads

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swrevealviewcontroller

So I have an odd bug that I am hoping someone can help me with. I have a UITableView with data being loaded from an array. **I have the datasource and the delegate set**, I am using SWRevealController and if I navigate to the tableview nothing shows up, if I navigate to another view and then navigate back to the tableview the data now shows up as intended. This bug started when I implemented SWRevealController, it worked fine before using this library...so I assume this is causing the problem, but after many different attempts to debug and fix it I am stuck, I have called tableView.reloadData(), still nothing…so any help at all would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Please provide more information/code. Specifically, when/where you are calling tableView.reloadData(), etc.

Comment: Hi I am calling it in both viewDidLoad, and viewDidAppear... I understand they both get called when the view first loads but I called it in both places just to be safe. I am calling it only on that view controller, I am doing more research and I am beginning to wonder if some how I should be calling it in a prepareForSegue or something like that, pre-view appearing?

Comment: Going to be really hard to diagnose without seeing some code. Sounds like the call to reloadData is in the right place. Is the array populated at that point? Is it possible you are calling it too early (i.e. before the array is populated). Again, very difficult to diagnose without more code.

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint on your calls to reloadData and looking at the value of the array.

Comment: Hi Mark thank you for trying to help! I figured it out.. The array was set up outside the class (my intent was to use it globally), I moved it back to the class level and the table is populating, I will have to figure out another solution for accessing the data in that array in other parts of the app, probably core data... thanks again!

Comment: Still I find it odd that it populated on the second pass but not the first...I will have to figure that one out...